# How to obtain average and total impact factor of publications for an academic?

Tags: bibliometrics, impact-factor

For a while ResearchGate provided something called **impact points**. It was calculated as the sum of the impact factors of all the publications an academic had. For example, if an author had been an author on four papers with impact factors 0, 2, 4, and 3. They would have 0 + 2 + 4 + 3 = 9 impact points. They've recently stopped reporting this value because supposedly they no longer believe impact factors are valid indicators of an individual article (of course, as a side note, they continue to report their own mysterious ResearchGate points which in addition to publications also weights things largely irrelevant to the research community, but relevant to encouraging behaviour on the site that they desire).

If you also knew the number of publications someone had, you could also quickly determine their average impact factor per publication.

I found the combination of average impact factor and the sum of impact factors to be a really useful metric when getting a quick feel for an academic's publication track record. In addition, I think that impact points seemed to provide a reasonable starting point for discussing some of the trade-offs in publication strategies between quality/significance and quantity.

Given that this site includes many who are mindful of the problems with metrics for evaluating academic output, allow me to justify why I like the combination of average impact factor per paper and the sum of impact factors (i.e., impact points):

- Person-specific citation based metrics (e.g., h-index, total citations, and so on), which are often cited as preferable, are heavily influenced by time. Citations accumulate over time. Thus, a young researcher a couple of years out of their PhD may have been publishing high quality work in top journals, but may have very few citations. In contrast, a researcher may have been publishing lots of publication at the mid-tier level for many years, and may have a lot of citations. This connection with time is more than the linear increase in publication output you might see given a research with consistent output each year. Instead, In a simplistic model, it is a multiplicative effect of average number of publications per year, time since first started publishing at that level, and average time between publications and now.
- While journal impact factor is field dependent, you can start to adjust for this mentally, if you know your field. For example, I'm in psychology, and it tends to have lower impact factors than psychiatry due to various citation practices. As an aside, it would also be useful to use other journal impact metrics to form the average or sum that are less field dependent (e.g., the SNIP or SJR).

Probably the biggest issue with impact points is that some authors have publications with many more co-authors, or have more or less first-author papers, although this is less of an issue if you focus on average impact factor per paper.

So my question is, **given that ResearchGate has stopped reporting impact points, is there an alternative provider where you can quickly obtain the sum or average impact factor of the publications of a given academic?**

Comment: Incoming comments about how useless bibliographic metrics are in 3.. 2.. 1...

Comment: _if an author had been an author on four papers with impact factors 0, 2, 4, and 3._ — What does it mean for a paper to have an impact factor of 2?  Impact factors are usually defined as _average_ citation counts over all publications in a particular journal in a particular time window.  By that standard definition, **individual papers do not have impact factors.**

Comment: @jeffE For the purposes of calculation, papers get the impact factor of the journal they are published in.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's just silly. If you insist on counting _something_, why not count citations to the individual paper, using Scopus or Google Scholar, for example, instead of an aggregate statistic to which the paper only makes a minuscule contribution?

Comment: @jeffE because citations are confounded by time since the paper was released. So, an older academic automatically looks so much better. For example, you might have a new academic with 10 papers all released in the last couple of years in top journals but with only a few citations. Then you have an more established academic with 20 papers in low tier publications with 100s of citations. I agree that 10  years after a paper is released citations start to become meaningful indicator of impact/potential, and there is a sense in which total citations are measure of "achieved fame".

Comment: But if you want to get a bibliometric measure of quality then I think that in the short term, something like the impact factor of the journal (or some other indicator of quality) is more useful than citations.

Comment: You mention that IFs vary by field but that if you know your field you can adjust for that. If you know your field, though, you will know the journals the author is publishing in and have an opinion about them that is probably more meaningful than their IF, so why not just scan the authors' publication lists?

Comment: @Significance I agree partially. A few counter arguments (a) impact points is a very quick synthesis (i.e., it's a single number that means you don't have to look at the journal of 30,40,50 or more publications to get that sense); (b) there are a lot of journals in my field and even people that are kind of in your area may cross-over with other subfields; (c) at the level of a discipline like psychology, say you're trying to judge your competitiveness for promotion, job or grant, you may be comparing yourself to people who publish in quite different journals.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I think in that case, IFs aren't very useful either. In psychology, for instance, I would bet that psychometrics journals will have quite different IFs from child development journals, regardless of the quality of the work. My field is hydroecological modelling. If I publish similar work in a good ecology journal, it should have a much higher IF than a good limnology journal, which is likely to have a higher IF than a good modelling journal.

Comment: @JeffE *aggregate statistic to which the paper only makes a minuscule contribution* That's not the idea here. The highest the IF of a given journal typically the higher the acceptance standards. That does not always work but in some contexts it's actually a pretty accurate proxy for individual article quality..

Comment: @CapeCode _The highest the IF of a given journal typically the higher the acceptance standards_ — [citation needed] [data needed]

Comment: @JeffE I *know* you don't like the impact factor. No use chanting that gospel to me a hundredth time. I said "in some contexts" but you probably had IF rage before reaching that part of my comment. Here's an article for you: http://benthamopen.com/ABSTRACT/TOECOLJ-1-1-14 But the IF of the journal isn't that high, so apply caution.

Comment: @CapeCode Acceptance rates are not a good proxy for quality, either; an argument that bad proxy A correlates with bad proxy B is not convincing.  In theoretical computer science, first-tier conferences have acceptances rate around 25%; whereas, second- and third-tier conferences tend to have acceptance rates around 25%. The main difference is self-selection: People submit stronger papers to better venues.

Comment: @JeffE I guess you don't have citations and data to show what makes a conference first-tier or whether it's effectively self-selection that is happening? My point is you know these things because you work in that field. In my field people also do self-selection based on journals IF, and sometimes settle for lower IFs upon rejection. The rule of thumb seems to be that under 2 the IF is mostly noise.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any specific tools like ResearchGate which provide an average impact factor for a researcher - maybe others know of something? However, you could fairly painlessly generate the average SJR/SNIP value for a researcher through SciVal in Scopus.

If you add a researcher in SciVal, then click on the **benchmarking** tab, and then click on **View list of Scopus Sources for the selected Researchers and Groups** this will bring up a list of journals the researcher has published in. You can then click on **Export** and download the list of journals, with their SJR/SNIP values into excel, where you can then just use the =AVERAGE formula to calculate the average. I just did this and it took me 3-4 mins max.

Back to your specific question, you could use InCites to follow a similar process as above to calculate a researchers average Journal Impact Factor (Thompson Reuters) however it's not as straightforward as SciVal. As far as I know, you can't generate an XLS list of journals a researcher has published in within InCites (so you would need to get this list somewhere else). You can however export a list of journals from InCites with their impact factors but you would then need to link your researchers list of journals with the incites list to collate the relevant impact factors. you could use excel VLOOKUP to do this and then calculate the average. This is a lot more effort though, so it would depend why you want this average measure of research impact in the first place and whether it might be enough to just use the scopus impact metrics.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. SciVal works. They also provide IPP which is similar to impact factor.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to looking at impact points that indexes a similar concept is citations in the last full year. This can readily be obtained for anyone with a Google Scholar profile. Author search on Scopus also shows it.

E.g., see the 2015 column below (e.g., go to [this example](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ), hold mouse over to see value):
[image: einstein scholar citation]

Impact factor is essentially the mean number of citations per article per year in a given journal (where for example if the year for gathering citations was 2008, the publication years would be 2006 and 2007). But there is also a five year impact factor which extends the number of years articles are considered (e.g., 2003-2007). Depending on the life cycle of citations in a given field and journal, expanding the window of time for considering articles may alter the estimate of mean citations per year. My main point is that the underlying construct that is being measured is **mean citations per article per year**.

Thus, in a rough sense, the impact factor provides a rough guide to how many citations per year an author can expect from a given article published in a journal with a given impact factor. Of course, the distribution of citations in articles is positively skewed, but as we aggregate over many papers, the central limit theorem will begin to kick in.

Thus, citations per year in the previous year is in some senses addressing the same concept as impact points (i.e., the sum of the journal impact factors of the papers that an author has published in). In particular, it doesn't double load on years as an academic (i.e., total citations double loads for both the time you had to publish more articles and time that those publications have had to accrue citations). There are of course a few differences:

- It is based on how much people cite the particular author rather than the journals that they publish in. In many respects this is a positive, because it is more aligned with the authors achievement.
- It is typically based on a smaller sample size than journal impact factors. So there is greater scope for outliers to skew the distribution. I.e., one or two papers with hundred or thousands of citations may distort the underlying pattern.
- It uses the full history of articles by the academic. Thus, depending on the citation patterns of the field and how old the authors articles are, this may introduce particular distortions. For example, older academics may have articles that have stopped being cited particularly in fast moving fields. In fields with citation half lives that are often over 10 years (like mathematics, psychology, and the social sciences), this should not be a problem for most active academics.

As an aside, all citation based metrics including impact factors are contingent on the database or articles used to specify articles and used to source citations. Google Scholar is quite inclusive. ISI Impact Factor has greater quality control and is less inclusive. So, from casual observation, It seems like  Google Scholar picks up a multiple of between 2 and 5 times more citations than ISI or Scopus. Thus, any comparisons need to be mindful of that.